# What is the difference between $U\wedge(U\wedge V)$ and $U\cdot(U\wedge V)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, multivariable-calculus, several-complex-variables

I know the $U\cdot(U\wedge V)$ means:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        i & j & k \\
        u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\
        v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\implies
        \begin{pmatrix}
        (u_2)(v_3)  -(u_3)(v_2) \\
        (v_1)(u_3)  -(v_3)(u_1) \\
        (u_1)(v_2)  -(u_2)(v_1) \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

but I dont understand $U\wedge(U\wedge V)$.

Comment: I don't understand the notation $U(\textrm{dot})(U^V)$. Usually this operation, the *cross product* is denoted $U \times V$. Sometimes the notation $U \wedge V$ is used, though this has at least two related meanings, so I'd avoid using the latter for now.

Comment: Check out how I've edited the first line of your question to make it into pretty math. Consider applying the same things elsewhere.

Comment: (The question has been edited since my previous comment.)

Comment: The difference between a scalar (in fact $0$) and a vector

Comment: Right: I decided to go with OP's chosen notation, since OP apparently only knows one notion of $\wedge$ -- the one you and I would call "cross product" -- and it seems kindest to stick with the familiar notation.

Comment: BTW, you've got the first formula wrong: the matrix thing (if you take the determinant) is really just $U \wedge V$; if you include the $U \cdot$ in front, you get a single number rather than a column vector. (And, as Henry points out, that number is always zero.)

Comment: This bothers me, the use of the wedge. I get the impression that people think the exterior product is the same as the cross product. The former is much more general and well-behaved. And they give different results even when both are defined.

Answer (score 1):

$U\cdot(U\wedge V)$ should be a scalar, since it is the result of a dot or scalar product.  Because $U\wedge V$ is orthogonal to $U$, it will be $0$

$U\wedge(U\wedge V)$ should be a vector, since it is the result of a cross or vector product.  Because $U\wedge V$ is orthogonal to $U$, and $U\wedge(U\wedge V)$ is orthogonal to both, it be a multiple of the part of $V$ orthogonal to $U$: it will be a zero vector (not a zero scalar) if $V$ is a multiple of $U$, while it will be a multiple of $V$ if $V$ is orthogonal to $U$

Answer (score 0):

If you understand $U\wedge V$, which is a vector, then there is nothing new with $U\wedge(U\wedge V)$. You can read it as $U\wedge W$ where $W:=U\wedge V$.

---

$U\wedge(U\wedge V)$ is  and coplanar with $U,V$ and orthogonal to $U$.